# I cannot find the searchableController or the view for the Searchable plugin in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-controller

I installed the searchable plugin on Grails and when I run my application I can browse to it and the searchable function works fine.

The only problem is that I cannot find the searchableController or even the view of it in my project. So I'm not able to edit anything or rewire the code to fit in another controller or view.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SearchableController and its views are located inside the searchable plugin, see $HOME/.grails/<version>/projects/<projectname>/plugins/searchable.

*Be warned:* it's a really bad idea to modify anything in $HOME/.grails manually unless you're sure what you're doing.

Instead you could either:

- download the plugin from svn/git and reference it as 'inplace' plugin. If you don't know about inplace plugins, just google for it.
- copy the SearchableController from $HOME/.grails to your project and modify it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. That was a good help! If I had 15+ rep i would have voted this up!